# How to read a single JSON field for a specific Java type with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to build a JPA CriteriaQuery from a client-provided JSON filter; that is, to query this Person POJO:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String name;

    public Date dateOfBirth;

}
```

a client would provide a JSON like this

```
{
    "$or": [
        { "name":        { "$beginsWith": "Jo" } },
        { "dateOfBirth": { "$lessThan":   "1983-01-01T00:00:00Z" } }
    ]       
}
```

When parsing this filter, I need to obtain the right Java type from the provided JSON values, e.g. a `Date` for `dateOfBirth`. Given that I can easily reach the `JsonNode` for `"1983-01-01T00:00:00Z"` and that Jackson's `ObjectMapper` knows somewhere what type to deserialize for the `dateOfBirth` field of `Person.class`, how can I get it? Ideally it would be something in the lines of:

```
// jsonNode is the JsonNode for "1983-01-01T00:00:00Z"

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(Person.class);
Date date = (Date) reader.asField("dateOfBirth").readValue(jsonNode);
```

That `asField()` method would do the magic to return a reader which will read a JSON `string` as Java `Date` (or more generally the type that the `ObjectMapper` would resolve applying [de]serializers annotated for that field).

**Note:** I'm not asking how to parse dates with Jackson, but how to read a value and get the object Jackson would deserialize normally, but for a nested field.

Comment: See http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates - Use @JsonFormat to format Date

Comment: @bodo `Date` is just an example type, it could be anything. I'll try to make the answer more clear.

Comment: This is an example how to convert json string which contains date format as String to Date. Is that what you have been searching for, isn't it?

Comment: Ok I see, this is an example with mixin (this is serializing to json, but it doesn't matter) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21751615/how-to-map-the-mixins-for-the-nested-json-response May be more accurate for your problem

Comment: @bodo Nope, I don't know to which type I need to deserialize the value, it could be anything. I need to tell `ObjectMapper` "deserialize this `JsonNode` as you would do if the node was for field `foo` of `MyBean.class`; since the `ObjectMapper` knows well, I'm trying to get this information.

Comment: Am I understand right, the `foo` should be any nested type?

Comment: @bodo Yes, `foo` could be any nested type.

Comment: I don't think this is achievable with Jackson ObjectMapper, I suppose that CriteriaQuery can contain a bunch of leafs with conditions, so I think you need to use [JacksonStreamingApi](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) or write bunch of custom deserializers.